Problema con app de android studio
estoy haciendo una app con android studio que es un chat la cosa es que cuando envió un mensaje y la app esta cerrada sale una notificación lo que solo me funciona cuando estoy con el emulador, cuando me descargo la app en un mobil real funciona todo correctamente lo que a la hora de que salgan las notificaciones no aparecen y en el emulador si. Adjunto  mi android manifest:
Android Manifest:
**<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
    <permission
        android:name="tu.paquete.de.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="tu.paquete.de.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/bable"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/bable_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.ChatApp"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/babble_logo"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/primary"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.ChatActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.UsersActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.SignUpActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.SignInActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.MainActivity" />
        <service
            android:name=".firebase.MessagingService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>
</manifest>**

